# how to map json with typescript interface?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

i have response from backendthat i am trying to map it to interface but its always throws interface properties undefined like in below case `Envelop` always coming undefined. Any idea what is implemented wrong here ?

interface.ts

```
export interface IResult {
    Envelop: Envelope;
}

export interface Envelope {
    $: $;
    Header: string;
    Body: Body;
}
export interface $ {
    "xmlns:soapenv": string;
}

export interface Body {
    "trk:TrackResponse": TrackShipment;
}
```

main.ts

```
public after(data: IResult){

        const result = data.Envelop.Body
        const response: any = result;
        return response;
    }
```

Json data from backend

```
"soapenv:Envelope": {
     "$": {
         "xmlns:soapenv": "http"
     },
     "soapenv:Header": "",
     "soapenv:Body": {
         "some test Data"
     }
 }
```

Comment: In your 'after' function, log out the data object. What keys exist on that object?
It seems like the property Envelop doesn't exist on the data object.
I would think this line: `const result = data.Envelop.Body` should look more like: `const result = data['soapenv:Envelope'];`

Comment: Your `Envelop`, `Header` and `Body` interface properties don't match the keys in the returned JSON.

Comment: Also, just FYI `"soapenv:Body": {
         "some test Data"
     }` is not valid json. It should be a key, value pair.

Comment: thats direct mapping to the data and i am getting the response by doing `const result = data['soapenv:Envelope'];` but i want to map it to interface and get it from there

Comment: "some test data" was just example i am getting undefined at first level `Envelop` can someone provide correct answer please

Answer (score 1):

Given your response JSON, your interfaces should look like this

```
export interface IResult {
    "soapenv:Envelope": Envelope;
}
export interface Envelope {
    $: $;
    "soapenv:Header": string;
    "soapenv:Body": Body;
}
export interface $ {
    "xmlns:soapenv": string;
}
export interface Body {
    "trk:TrackResponse": TrackShipment;
}
```

Which you would then access like

```
public after(data: IResult) {
  const result: Body = data["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"];
  return result;
}
```

Comment: How de we access that in the main.ts ?

Comment: can not find name `Body` , where its coming from ?

Comment: `Body` is the `Body` interface. If you don't have access to it in main.ts because it's in a different file, import it at the top. `import { IResult, Body } from 'path/to/file';`

Comment: i have imported the interface not sure its always throwing undefined on Body or any property i tried to map

Comment: What does your `map` look like?

Comment: its actually commented out except one line `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });`

Comment: what do you mean by map ?

Comment: You said you tried to map properties, [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an array method.